# How to read json response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have a json response in the form of data with format like this. It is part of the whole data released

[JSON Data Here](http://pastebin.com/nG6bPzJw)

I have made ​​a script to read the data :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('http://services.berthojoris.com/json/baca2.php', function(data) {
       for(var i=0; i<data[0].actionDetails.length;i++){
          document.write('Judul Halaman : '+ data[1].actionDetails[i].pageTitle+"<br>");
          document.write('URL : '+ data[1].actionDetails[i].url+"<hr>");
       }
   });
});
```

But the data generated using getJSON only 1, 2 or 5 data. While there are actually a lot of results generated process.

[image: Result]

How do I capture all of the data generated??

I just wanted to take the **pageTitle** and **url** data from the data.

Comment: If you translate the following sentences to english, someone might understand your question and be able to help:   "But the data generated using getJSON only 1, 2 or 5 data. While there are actually a lot of results generated process. How do I capture all of the data generated??"

Comment: @pabrams I apologize for the language used..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, you are mixing `data[0]` and `data[1]` (it will display all action details from the first item in the `data` array)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('http://services.berthojoris.com/json/baca2.php', function(data) {
       for(var i=0; i<data[0].actionDetails.length;i++){
          document.write('Judul Halaman : '+ data[0].actionDetails[i].pageTitle+"<br>");
          document.write('URL : '+ data[0].actionDetails[i].url+"<hr>");
       }
   });
});
```

If you want to display all action items in data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://services.berthojoris.com/json/baca2.php', function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(idx, item){
            $.each(item.actionDetails, function(idx, actionDetail){
                document.write('Judul Halaman : '+ actionDetail.pageTitle+"<br>");
                document.write('URL : '+ actionDetail.url+"<hr>");
            })
        })
    });
});
```

Also note, you may have to use `$('body').append(string)` instead of `document.write(string)`

Comment: Many Thanks Arun..:)
I apologize for the language used if too weird .. :)